# How to download all dependencies of RPM to offline instalation

Tags: rpm, suse, sles, zypper

I have SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 SP5 and RPM which should be installed offline.
How to download all dependencies of RPM to transfer them to offline machine with same OS?

Comment: Off-topc here - ask on [su]. This place for for programming questions not setup & admin.

Comment: It's quite funny, because I've got exactly the same problem as yours, maybe I ended on the same project as you?...

Answer (score 2):

I think the best option to install a package and ensure all the dependencies are ok, is implement a local repository, this is an offline method to solve the problem.

To execute this procedure, you need to follow the [next steps](https://es.opensuse.org/Zypper#Agregar_repositorios).

First you need to upload the OS ISO to the machine or attach it as an external disk.
Once the ISO is on the server, you need to mount as a FS, with the following command.

```
    mount /SLE-15-SP3-Full-x86_64-GM-Media1.iso /mnt
```

NOTE: For the command above, please replace the path and name or your specific ISO.

When the ISO is mounted, you need to especified to the OS that you want to implement a local repo.

Add repo
zypper ar /mnt SLES-Packages

Build repo cache

```
 zypper ref
```

Now you can start to use this repo, you can try searching for a package.

```
Search packages
 zypper se -s yast
```

BR.